# How to persuade Java Web Start to actually remember password?

Tags: java-web-start

I use Java Web Start. The file is on http server, that needs name and password (it's windows server). What the Java Web start does is this (with user and IP redacted):

[image: java web start]

The same on MS Windows client. There is this "Save this password in your password list" option, that does nothing at all (on both Mac OS and Windows), when running this java web start app again, it wants the password again.

Is it a bug in JWS? Or what is going on exactly?

Comment: It is probable that the wording is a little different in the windows version of JWS; however, the results are the same.

Comment: No, it's not different, it's 100% the same.

Comment: I didn't. I actually set it without any password and programmed my own authorization scheme. Java WS is strange.

Comment: My servlet handles the auth headers on its own. I made some debug to know what's going on. If i launch the program for the second time from the desktop shortcut Web Start doesn't seem to send any `Authorization` header so i have to send a `WWW-Authenticate` header again :( Some of our customers says that saving the password works seldomly but just until they don't restart their machines. Looks like this works completely unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.

turns out you need to restart your web browser to have the java remember your password.

I also allowed that java cache, but i dont think that was the solution.

Comment: I cannot really accept it right now, because I used a workaround already and I don't know if this would help. I will probably try it once again when I got time and accept your answer if it works

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a workaround for this problem. You can use some kind of cookie based authentication for supporting password authentication.

In my case when a successfull login happens using the HTTP basic authentication i send a cookie in my servlet which holds the username and password the same way the HTTP header contains it when Basic method is used (BASE64 encoded). Web Start stores this cookie in Internet Explorer's cookie store on Windows (on other systems Web Start has it's own cookie store). Web Start then sends this cookie everytime a resource is being accessed from my domain. You can specify a very long lifetime for the cookie (like 10 years) which will probably outlasts the current OS installation anyway.

On subsequent requests i check for the present of the cookie and try to validate the user according to that. If the Cookie auth is invalid and no HTTP `Authorization` header received (or that's invalid also) i'm sending the `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` status.

The disadvantage is that username and password is being stored as a cookie on the computer. The password is being sent through the network the same way as with HTTP Basic authentication just in a different header so you can protect it with HTTPS.

This also solves the lack of password remembering option on Linux Web Start.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the cookie idea, the trouble is now, how do you clear the cookie, if you want to? I mean, nice that the cookie is persistent, but what if the user wants to clear the cookie? As far as I see, the Java console has no option to do it. Clearing the web start cache doesn't seem to do it. On Windows, supposedly IE stores it, so IE gives an interface (haven't tested it myself). But on Mac and presumably Linux, I just can't find out where they are stored. Tried looking in preferences files, and tried blowing away the whole Java cache folder, but they are still stored somewhere. Anyone have an idea?